# How can I apply a custom (defined) order to the rows of a row chart in DC.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a rowchart that currently looks like this:

```
deltaChart
    .width(300)
    .height(250)
    .dimension(deltaDim)
    .group(pointsByDelta)
    .xAxis().ticks(4);
```

In which the `deltaDim` dimension is comprised of 11 or so unique string values, `pointsByDelta` represents related counts, and `deltaChart` is of type rowChart.

Since the `deltaDim` values are string and not numeric, the sorting is out of order.  I've tried applying what I've found in the wiki as well as on other's posts here to manually reorder, with no luck at all.  Regardless of the format I receive a console error: .ordering is not a function()

I've tried just simple ordering like this:

```
.ordering(function(d){return -d.value})
```

That results in error. Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
.ordering(function(d) {
        if(d.value == "5 ft") return 0;
        else if(d.value == "4 ft") return 1;
        else if(d.value == "3 ft") return 2;
        else if(d.value == "2 ft") return 3;
        else if(d.value == "1 ft") return 4;
        else if(d.value == "0 ft") return 5;
        else if(d.value == "-1 ft") return 6;
        else if(d.value == "-2 ft") return 7;
        else if(d.value == "-3 ft") return 8;
        else if(d.value == "-4 ft") return 9;
        else if(d.value == "-5 ft") return 10;
        else return 11;
    })
```

It looks like most of the posts on this topic are responded to with a way to sort in ascending or descending order.  I've not even been able to get that to behave, and in my case, I need to be able to dictate the order if possible.

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure why people are answering questions about String, that's pretty far off base. Maybe you're using a really old version of dc.js that doesn't support this function? It was introduced in 1.5 or 1.6. What you show above should work.

Comment: Gordon, thank you for the note.  I doubled checked, I am using 1.6.  From other examples I've seen I thought it looked as though it should work... I'm really scratching my head as to why I'm getting the error, even with the less complex ordering.

Comment: Hmm, could it be that you are attempting to call [`.ordering(...)` after a call to `.xAxis(...)`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#why-does-everything-break-after-a-call-to-xaxis-or-yaxis)? If you're getting ".ordering is not a function" that means it either doesn't exist or you're not working with the chart object - it won't matter what you try to pass to it.

Comment: Its definitely the chart object, for example: `var deltaChart = dc.rowChart("#bfeDelta-chart");`  Then `bfeDeltaChart
 .width(300)
        .height(250)
        .dimension(bfeDeltaDim)
        .group(pointsByBFEDelta)
        .xAxis().ticks(4)
 .ordering(function(d){return +d.value});`

Comment: Please look at the FAQ link I posted above. Using `.xAxis()` will return a different object which is not the chart.

Comment: Interestingly, if I comment out the `.xAxis(...)` I don't then get the error, but I also do not see any change in ordering, even with the full preferred function in place.  So your link to the above FAQ text is great, thank you.  Now I guess I just need to fiddle with the ordering call.

Comment: Great, lmk if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined with Gordon's input from above regarding .xAxis(), the solution that works is as follows.

```
deltaChart
    .width(300)
    .height(250)
    .dimension(bfeDeltaDim)
    .group(pointsByBFEDelta)
    .ordering(function(d) {
        if(d.key == "5 ft") return 0;
        else if(d.key == "4 ft") return 1;
        else if(d.key == "3 ft") return 2;
        else if(d.key == "2 ft") return 3;
        else if(d.key == "1 ft") return 4;
        else if(d.key == "0 ft") return 5;
        else if(d.key == "-1 ft") return 6;
        else if(d.key == "-2 ft") return 7;
        else if(d.key == "-3 ft") return 8;
        else if(d.key == "-4 ft") return 9;
        else if(d.key == "-5 ft") return 10;
        else return 11;
    })
    .xAxis().ticks(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the strings are like they are above you could work with them in the function.
**Split:**

> The split() method splits a String object into an array of strings by
>   separating the string into substrings.

split the string by the space in the string and then return the first item in the array
Then parse this item, which will be 5 to -5 into an int

```
.ordering(function(d){  
     return parseInt(d.split(" ")[0]);  
 })
```

- Looking into this `.ordering()` is available with dc.js - but only on
  the dc object
  https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#orderingorderfunction
- d3 v3 `sort()` -
  https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#sort

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure d3.js has an `.ordering()` method? Perhaps you are looking for the good old `.sort()`. The issue is that you have to replace the unit "ft" when iterating through the array, and we can use the regex pattern `\s+ft$` to remove that. The pattern matches the term `<any_amount_of_space>ft` at the end of the string. After replacement, simply convert it to a float. I avoid using `parseInt()` because you might have non-integer values.

```js
var arr = ["5 ft", "4 ft", "3 ft", "2 ft", "1 ft", "0 ft", "-1 ft", "-2 ft", "-3 ft", "-4 ft", "-5 ft"];

var arr_sorted = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  // Convert to float
  var x = parseFloat(a.replace(/\s+ft$/, "")),
      y = parseFloat(b.replace(/\s+ft$/, ""));

  // Return, sort by descending order
  return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));

  // If ascending order is needed, use:
  // return ((x > y) ? 1 : ((x < y) ? -1 : 0));
});
console.log(arr_sorted);
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to avoid the lengthy if else condition. This can be easily handled through [d3 scales](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Ordinal-Scales.md)

1. Create the ordinal scale and domain with the preferred order.
2. Range can be done with the index by sorting order

   ```
   var scale = d3.scale.ordinal()
   .domain(['C','B','A'])
   .range([0,1,2]);
   ```

   In ordering function

   ```
   chart.ordering(function(k){
     return scale(k.key);
   })
   ```

[jsFiddle Working copy](http://fiddle.jshell.net/caravinden/7bL3985k/)